# How to read Oozie URL variable

Tags: hadoop, oozie, bigdata

How can I read the oozie url variable using shell command?

I tried the http://localhost:11000 but does not work.

Comment: Oozie url is `http://localhost:11000/oozie`. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am looking to get list of all the jobs that have failed today on oozie.

Comment: You can use the `oozie job -filter` command. Pass all the required parameter. https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.0/DG_CommandLineTool.html#Oozie_job_operation_commands

Comment: I get below error:
`$oozie jobs -filter status=RUNNING
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Oozie URL is not available neither in command option or in the environment`

Comment: oozie jobs -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -filter status=RUNNING

Comment: If I use `job` instead of `jobs`then it says `Invalid sub-command: Missing required option:`

Comment: sorry my bad, please use appropriate.

Comment: It seems the Oozie URL is not available from the error message but the jobs run fine through HUE interface on same server.

Comment: I have never used HUE. Find the Oozie server URL and use it.

Comment: Is there a shell command to find it?

Comment: I think all the Oozie commands will need to oozie server. You can try `oozie admin -servers`. otherwise check oozie conf file `oozie-site.xml`.

Comment: Many Thanks for the quick replies.